# Ansible -- The offending line appears to be:

Tags: ansible, syntax

I'm trying to implement a playbook to grab the external IP address at a few locations but it keeps giving me this same error:

```
The offending line appears to be:

  remote_user: pi
   tasks:
        ^ here
```

I've messed around with the indentation a few times, to no avail. Any help is appreciated, I'm new to this and still learning so there may be something I'm missing (playbook below)

```
- name: See if location is running on cradlepoint
  hosts: cradlepoints
  remote_user: pi
   tasks:
   - name: Grab External IP
     dig:
     - +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
   - name: Print a message
     debug:
      msg: 'Here Ya Go'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The indendation is wrong, `tasks` should be on the same level as `hosts` and `remote_user`.

```yaml
- name: See if location is running on cradlepoint
  hosts: cradlepoints
  remote_user: pi
  tasks:
  - name: Grab External IP
    dig:
    - +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
  - name: Print a message
    debug:
      msg: 'Here Ya Go'
```

The main problem seems to be your usage of the [`dig` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/dig_lookup.html), which is nothing like what's documented. It's intended to be used as a lookup module.

```yaml
  - ansible.builtin.debug:
      msg: "{{ lookup('community.general.dig', 'myip.opendns.com.')}}"
```

It looks like you were actually tring to run the `dig` shell command.

```yaml
  - shell: "dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com"
    register: myip
  - debug:
      var: myip
```